# Python fill a list with the same string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame and I would like to make a new column with the same string in each row.

Currently I'm doing this.

```
tag=[]
for x in xrange(len(preds)): #preds is a np.array, same length of df
    tag.append('MY STRING')
 df['TAG']=tag
```

I know there must be a smarter way to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `df['TAG'] = 'MY STRING'`

Comment: [adding/deleting columns](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/04%20-%20Lesson.ipynb) - pandas lesson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df['TAG'] = ['MY STRING'] * len(preds)`